# Javascript/jQuery: programmatically follow a link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

In Javascript code, I would like to programmatically cause the browser to follow a link that's on my page. Simple case:

```
<a id="foo" href="mailto:somebody@example.com">something</a>
```

---

```
function goToBar() {
   $('#foo').trigger('follow');
}
```

This is hypothetical as it doesn't actually work. And no, triggering `click` doesn't do it.

I am aware of `window.location` and `window.open` but these differ from native link-following in some ways that matter to me: a) in the presence of a `<base />` element, and b) in the case of `mailto` URLs. The latter in particular is significant. In Firefox at least, calling `window.location.href = "mailto:somebody@example.com"` causes the window's `unload` handlers to fire, whereas simply clicking a `mailto` link does not, as far as I can tell.

I'm looking for a way to trigger the browser's default handling of links, from Javascript code.

Does such a mechanism exist? Toolkit-specific answers also welcome (especially for Gecko).

Comment: why not just use a target="_blank" attribute in your mailto: link?

Comment: I can, but that leaves a blank window open, whereas without that my mail client opens but my browser stays as is, which is what I want.

Comment: Your jsFiddle examples work for me with Firefox Aurora 14.0a2 (2012-06-04).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as I know, window.location does exactly what you are looking for, triggering the browser's default link clicking behavior.

Some browsers notice the protocol before any events are fired or the actual href is changed.

```
window.location = "mailto:somebody@example.com";
```

Trying the fiddle demo mentioned below I get the following results:

- Chromium: fires `onbeforeunload` with the button and link
- Firefox fires `onbeforeunload` only for the button
- Safari: never fires `onbeforeunload`
- Opera: same as Safari

So a good way to prevent the `unload` event from being fired is by returning false in `beforeunload`.

Comment: No, not quite the same. See http://jsfiddle.net/eyS6x/2/. "Click me" calls the `beforeunload` handler, the link itself doesn't.

Comment: Fair enough, I tested this in multiple browsers now and it seems behavior is quite different. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Well, you may be on to something here. In my real code it's _only_ `beforeunload` and not `unload` that I have. I messed that up in my OP. Is there a way _inside_ my `beforeunload` handler that I can detect whether it's a mailto?

Comment: The OP is not asking how to mimic the link behavior, he is asking how to produce the exact same behavior as clicking the link. Even if it wasn't firing a `onbeforeunload` it would still be wrong because it wouldn't trigger the `click` event on the link.

Comment: No, actually the OP is specifically asking how "to trigger the browser's default handling of links". Which in my opinion doesn't mean the actual click of a link but mainly what happens after the click, such as following URLs or triggering associated events.

Comment: @Dan, you can't really query the location object since it only returns the current state, which is the current url. However, you could use a variable to store which link you just called. I extended your fiddle a little bit to show this. Of course for production code you wouldn't use a global variable but it shows the basic principle.

Answer (score 6):

**METHOD 1** click method

`HTMLElement`s have a method `click()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click

```
function goToBar() {
   document.getElementById('foo').click();
}
```

---

**Method 2** Firing synthetic events

I wonder why saluce deleted his answer. That solution is what I've used in the past (when click was an IE only thing). That is, firing a synthetic browser event (not a fake one like jQuery's `click()`). Let me post a solution using that idea...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/eyS6x/3/**

```
/**
 * Fire an event handler to the specified node. Event handlers can detect that the event was fired programatically
 * by testing for a 'synthetic=true' property on the event object
 * @param {HTMLNode} node The node to fire the event handler on.
 * @param {String} eventName The name of the event without the "on" (e.g., "focus")
 */
function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
  // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
  var doc;
  if (node.ownerDocument) {
    doc = node.ownerDocument;
  } else if (node.nodeType == 9 /** DOCUMENT_NODE */){
    // the node may be the document itself
    doc = node;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + +node.tagName + "#" + node.id);
  }

  if (node.fireEvent) {
    // IE-style
    var event = doc.createEventObject();
    event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
    node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
  } else if (node.dispatchEvent) {
    // Gecko-style approach is much more difficult.
    var eventClass = "";

    // Different events have different event classes.
    // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
    // the event firing is going to fail.
    switch (eventName) {
      case "click":
      case "mousedown":
      case "mouseup":
        eventClass = "MouseEvents";
        break;

      case "focus":
      case "change":
      case "blur":
      case "select":
        eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
        break;

      default:
        throw "JSUtil.fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
        break;
    }
    var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);
    var bubbles = eventName == "change" ? false : true;  
    event.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

    event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
    node.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
};

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
   fireEvent( document.getElementById('link'), 'click');
}
```

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. Try http://jsfiddle.net/eyS6x/1/ and click "Click Me". This is in Firefox 5.0 for MacOS.

Comment: It works on Chrome (19.0.1084.52 m), Firefox (10.0.3) and IE (8.0.7600) on Windows. It may be a Mac problem.

Comment: That may be. I'll test a couple of more places.

Comment: @Dan Try out the new solution I posted, I don't have a mac to test it

Comment: Well, I have learned something new from  your post, so +1 for that, but unfortunately it doesn't work, at least in jsFiddle. Chrome throws the error "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." and Firefox 5 appears not to do anything at all.

Comment: @Dan, I had a friend try it. Doesn't work for FF/Chrome on the Mac, it does work for Safari on the Mac.