# Sending email from client

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

We are developing an application that requires serious security. Now, my problem is that client enters a password, and that password should be sent to another client in an email. The key point here is that even the server should not see the password, so the client must send the email directly to another client through the application using client-side stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer the Data from one client to another by email you must go through a server. In this situation what I recommend is encoding the password with a key that only the clients have access to, thus making it unreadable to the server. Or having the key stored on a different server.

Comment: I'm confused.  If your application requires serious security, you would never send the password in email.  Email is not secure.  If you _must_ send email from the client, you should be able to build a mailto: anchor link in html with the appropriate text. You would have to build this dynamically with jquery or other means to manipulate the DOM.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto  also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906197/javascript-jquery-programmatically-follow-a-link

Comment: Nice but its not my requirement i specified the same solution to my client but he is not accepting...

Answer (score 1):

You will need an email server that you can install on the client.

There are several Python based email servers.   FreeSMTP is easy to install and configure but is only free for 10 emails per day - but certainly easy to get going for proof of concept.

Finally you will need to talk to the email server from your client code.   It is not clear from your question whether you client is Flex or JavaScript.   If you are using Flex, then SMTPMailer might help.   http://code.google.com/p/smtpmailer/.   It might not be possible to do this with JavaScript - see [Javascript IMAP and SMTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775191/javascript-imap-and-smtp-client).

The concept doesn't seem to be a good one though.   Instead can you send a non reversible hash derived from the password - then the server will never see the password - but the hash may still be useful for authentication purposes.